# Generate random questions

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've made a webpage and used JavaScript to ask 5 maths questions, however I'd like to edit my code so I am able to generate questions using random numbers. I'm sure I'm meant to use the Math.random function but I'm not quite sure. Here's my current code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <h1>A Simple Maths Game!</h1>

  <p>Welcome to an awesome maths game! Your aim is simple, just answer all maths questions that you see! <br> Goodluck!</p>

  <script>

    // Maths question 1

    var userAnswer;
    userAnswer = prompt("1. 4 + 5");

    if (userAnswer == 9){
        document.write("1. 4 + 5 = <span class = 'correct'" + userAnswer + "</span> correct");
        // document.write("\n");
        document.write("<br>");
    }
    else{
        document.write("1. 4 + 5 = <span class = 'incorrect'" + userAnswer + "</span> incorrect");
        document.write("<br>");
    }

    // Maths question 2

    var userAnswer;
    userAnswer = prompt("2. 19 + 4");

    if (userAnswer == 23){
        document.write("2. 19 + 4 = <span class = 'correct'" + userAnswer + "</span> correct");
        document.write("<br>");
        }
    else{
        document.write("2. 19 + 4 = <span class = 'incorrect'" + userAnswer + "</span> incorrect"); 
        document.write("<br>");
    }

    // Maths question 3

    var userAnswer;
    userAnswer = prompt("3. 5 x 5");

    if (userAnswer == 25){
        document.write("3. 5 x 5 = <span class = 'correct'" + userAnswer + "</span> correct");
        document.write("<br>");
    }
    else{
        document.write("3. 5 x 5 = <span class = 'incorrect'" + userAnswer + "</span> incorrect"); 
        document.write("<br>");
    }

    // Maths question 4

    var userAnswer;
    userAnswer = prompt("4. 7 x 5");
    if (userAnswer == 35){
        document.write("4. 7 x 5 = <span class = 'correct'" + userAnswer + "</span> correct");
        document.write("<br>");
    }
    else{
        document.write("4. 7 x 5 = <span class = 'incorrect'" + userAnswer + "</span> incorrect"); 
        document.write("<br>");
    }

    // Maths question 5

    var userAnswer;
    userAnswer = prompt("5. 8 x 8");
    if (userAnswer == 64){
        document.write("5. 8 x 8 = <span class = 'correct'" + userAnswer + "</span> correct");
        document.write("<br>");
    }
    else{
        document.write("5. 8 x 8 = <span class = 'incorrect'" + userAnswer + "</span> incorrect"); 
        document.write("<br>");
    }


  </script>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance, I appreciate any help.

Comment: I am missing your attempt in the code to integrate variable results and variable questions (regardless how you are generating these random numbers). Also, why don't you want to use `Math.random()`. You said that you are not sure. Why is that? On a personal note I'd also like to recommend that you format your questions differently: you are asking `1.  4  +  5` and expect nine. Are you sure nobody will answer `6.4`?

Comment: Also, `document.write` has all kinds of problems. Try to avoid it in future projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate random numbers, do the math to get the answer your expect, and then compare your expected answer with the actual answer of the user :

```
var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10); // A number between 0 and 10
var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10); // Another number between 0 and 10

var expectedAnswer = a + b;

var answer = prompt(a + " + " + b);

if (answer == expectedAnswer)
    alert('Good job !');
else
    alert('Wrong answer :()');
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/y7184yz2/1/)

Of course this is a simple sample with only additions, but you can go further and use the same random system to choose an operation like substraction etc...

Comment: for more about numbers generated in random visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Comment: Although your answer is partly correct, you can clearly see that there's multiplication in the question as well. This isn't going to work for that.

Comment: I am giving an advice and suggesting a way to solve the problem, not giving the entiere code for OP specific program. From my point of view, this is SO philosophy